# provide type for destructure in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have some code that need to use destructure as following but I get the error `Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.`, I guess I can fix the error by using any type `let user:any = {};` but that against the eslint rule from application. any other way for me to walk around it?

```
let user = {};

user.name = 'John';
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript often works best when within a functional, or at least immutable, paradigm. Define objects all at once whenever possible, and then all you have to do is allow the automatic type-checker to do its work.

```
const user = {
  name: 'John'
};
```